# count times an element shows up in a linkedlist Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a method that allows me to count how many times an element of type String shows up in a LinkedList of type Strings. 
my code shown below does not work. I keep getting index out of bounds in the line i commented on down below. Can't seem to find the bug

```
public int findDuplicate (LinkedList<String> e) {
    int j = 1;
    LinkedList<String> test = e;
    while (!test.isEmpty()){
        test = e;
        String value = test.pop();
        //Screws up here when i = 6 
        for(int i =0; i<=test.size() && test.get(i)!=null; i++){ 
            String value3 = test.get(i);
            if(e.get(i).equals(value) && i<=test.size()){
                String value2 = test.get(i); 
                j++;
                String Duplicate = e.get(i);
                e.remove(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(value + " is listed " + j + " times");

    }
    return j;
}
```

using hashmaps.. still doesn't work
public void findDuplicate (LinkedList e) {

```
        Map<String,Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        while(!e.isEmpty()){
            String value = e.pop();
            for(int i =0; i<e.size(); i++){
                counts.put(value, i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counts.toString());
}
```

Comment: `i < test.size()` or `i <= test.size() - 1`. Reasoning is that arrays in most of programming languages are 0-indexed.

Answer (score 5):

It seems clear from how you use `test` and `e` that you expect them to be two separate, independent objects. In fact, they are not. When you perform the following assignment:

```
    test = e;
```

both `test` and `e` end up pointing to the same list. When you change one, they both change.

As to a good way to solve the problem, you might want to use a `Map<String,Integer>` to count how many times each unique string appears in the list. You can then iterate over the list just once, populating the map. At the end, the map will give the final counts.

Comment: if, I'm not mistaken you are suggesting I use hashmaps? I looked in the Java Api, Can you point me to where i should look within the api to figure out how to initialize a Map? I don't yet understand how to use the API. i think this is how Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));

Comment: @Ali: Just use `Map<String,Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`

Answer (score 2):

Indices are from 0 to `test.size()-1`. Try to use:

```
for(int i =0; i<test.size() && test.get(i)!=null; i++){ 
...
```

And, as @NPE pointed out this code is not going to work right, because `e` and `test` share the same object.